# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str with JSON parsing

Tags: python, json

I am getting the above error when trying to parse a JSON file.

**Code:**

```
import json

data = open('output.json').read()

for host in data['ASSET_DATA_REPORT']['HOST_LIST']['HOST']:
        print(host['IMAGE_ID'])
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_format.py", line 11, in <module>
    for host in data['ASSET_DATA_REPORT']['HOST_LIST']['HOST']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

**JSON:**

```
{
"ASSET_DATA_REPORT": {
  "HOST_LIST": {
            "HOST": [
                {
                    "IP": {
                        "network_id": "0"
                    }, 
                    "TRACKING_METHOD": "EC2", 
                    "ASSET_TAGS": {
                        "ASSET_TAG": [
                            "EC2 Running", 
                            "IF - Database - MySQL", 
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "DNS": "i-xxxxxxx", 
                    "EC2_INSTANCE_ID": "i-xxxxxx", 
                    "EC2_INFO": {
                        "PUBLIC_DNS_NAME": "ec2-xxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com", 
                        "IMAGE_ID": "ami-xxxxxx", 
                        "VPC_ID": "vpc-xxxxxx", 
                        "INSTANCE_STATE": "RUNNING", 
                        "PRIVATE_DNS_NAME": "ip-xxxx.ec2.internal", 
                        "INSTANCE_TYPE": "m3.xlarge"
                 }
             }
          ]
       }
    }
}
```

It seems like `host` is a string for some reason and I'm not sure how to overcome this error.

Comment: You import `json` but don't use it. Open the file and `json.load(file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple problems, some in your code, some in your JSON.

First, the JSON --- you have an extra comma after the last list entry:

```
"ASSET_TAG": [
    "EC2 Running",
    "IF - Database - MySQL",
]
```

Your code has two problems.
First is that you never convert the contents of the file to JSON --- it remains a string:

```
data = open('output.json').read()
```

You want something like
[roganjosh already described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938132/4116239):

```
with open('output.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Your followup problem is that the structure of the JSON doesn't match your code.
`'IMAGE_ID'` isn't a key in the
(unnamed)
dictionary stored in the `'HOST'` list --- it's a key of the `'EC2_INFO'` dictionary, which is contained inside that nameless dictionary.
This:

```
print(host['IMAGE_ID'])
```

Should be something like:

```
print(host['EC2_INFO']['IMAGE_ID'])
```

The output is a string:

```
ami-xxxxxx
```

Comment: I see that now. This is correct and worked after I tested as well.

Answer (score 3):

Importing `json` is not enough. `data = open('output.json').read()` just treats it as any other file.

`TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` is not complaining about the `'HOST'` key; `data['ASSET_DATA_REPORT']` on its own won't be valid either because the whole thing is a string.

Try:

```
with open('output.json') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
```

As pointed out by @Milton Arango G there is an error in the JSON you posted. Change:

```
"IF - Database - MySQL",
```

to:

```
"IF - Database - MySQL"
```

After that, you can obtain the `'IMAGE_ID'` field with:

```
print(data['ASSET_DATA_REPORT']['HOST_LIST']['HOST'][0]['EC2_INFO']['IMAGE_ID'])
```

Comment: That returns the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_format.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(host['IMAGE_ID'])
KeyError: 'IMAGE_ID'`

Comment: Also there is an error in your json file that makes it unable to be decoded you could check it with [JsonFormatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Just remove the comma in ```"IF - Database - MySQL", ``` and roganjosh answer should work or you could iterate it with the for loop you have there.

Comment: @NickD. that's unrelated, you now have a nested dictionary and list structure that you can actually access. `host['IMAGE_ID']` will not let you access the `'IMAGE_ID'` key but it'll take me a little to get at that key. Hold on.

Comment: @MiltonArangoG good spot, thanks. Credited you in the answer,

Comment: @NickD. Edited for the JSON fix (which I think was your copy/paste error as it's not possible to read the file otherwise) and to show you how to access your requested value.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a good way to open a json file.
`open('output.json').read()`
return your file as string.
A better way is :

```
import json

with open('output.json', 'r') as my_file:
    data = json.load(my_file)

for host in data['ASSET_DATA_REPORT']['HOST_LIST']['HOST']:
        print(host['IMAGE_ID'])
```